# Why does command substitution not work in braces but replacing it with the actual number works?

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell-script, bash-scripting

I'm using the following command to try to max out the number of cores on my server:

```
for i in {1..`nproc --all`}; do while : ; do : ; done & done
```

For some reason, it only ever uses one core, even though my server has two. If I try to replace `` `nproc --all` `` with `2`, it works fine. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brace expansion happens before command substitution. This fragment

```
{1..`nproc --all`}
```

will not be expanded as brace at all. When the command substitution is expanded to `2`, it becomes

```
{1..2}
```

but it's too late for brace expansion now. The same problem would be [if you used a variable there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/169511/10765659).

---

This syntax works:

```
for ((i=1; i<=`nproc --all`; i++)); do echo "$i"; done
```

or

```
for i in $(seq 1 "$(nproc --all)"); do echo "$i"; done
```

Adjust the loop to your needs. Note in the last case I used `$(…)` instead of `` `…` `` because [this form nests easily](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4708549/10765659).